# Distribution equation.

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Solve in $D'$( **distribution**),

$(x^2-a^2) T =\delta_{b} $.   $(1)$.

Where $\delta$  is the Dirac distribution. 
I find the *homogeneous* solution of $(1)$, which  is  $T_0=A\delta_{a} +B\delta'_{-a} $   but I don't able to find the *particular* Solution .
Any hint.

Comment: If $a \neq b$ then $1/(x^2-a^2)$ is smooth at $b$ so $T_{\text{particular}} = \delta_b/(x^2-a^2) = \delta_b/(b^2-a^2)$ is defined.

Comment: When $a = b$ you can take $T_{\text{particular}} = \frac12 \delta_b''.$

Comment: Thanks you. When a=b then $T_p=A\delta_b $ so I search $A $.

Comment: But $(x^2-a^2) \delta_b = (b^2-a^2) \delta_b = 0$ when $a=b$ so $A \delta_b$ is not a particular solution.

Comment: This question is identical to the question you have asked a day before :
 (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2592872). Please, don't do that ! It's not a fair practice on this site : imagine that everybody does it.... I advise you to erase the previous question.

Comment: I couldn't delete it. Help me to delete